# How to redirect WooCommerce shop URL?

Tags: customization, woocommerce-offtopic

Is there any way to redirect WooCommerce default 'http://website.com/shop/' URL to 'http://website.com/shop/all/'?

After a long research found this : 
[How does Wordpress redirect to WooCommerce shop page?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/151397/how-does-wordpress-redirect-to-woocommerce-shop-page) but not works as i expect

So you Have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You can use woocommerce_return_to_shop_redirect filter to overwrite the redirection url.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_return_to_shop_redirect', "custom_woocommerce_return_to_shop_redirect" ,20 );
function custom_woocommerce_return_to_shop_redirect(){
   return site_url()."shop/all/";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Swarnendu Paul answer is great, I'd just replace **site_url().'shop/all'** with **home_url('/shop/all')** in case the home url and site url are not the same :)

so, it'd be:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_return_to_shop_redirect', "custom_woocommerce_return_to_shop_redirect" ,20 ); 
function custom_woocommerce_return_to_shop_redirect(){
    return home_url('shop/all/');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

for 2017 try:

```
function custom_shop_page_redirect() {
    if( is_shop() ){
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/shop/all/' ) );
        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'custom_shop_page_redirect' );
```